# SizeforItematIndexPath in F# Xamarin

Tags: ios, f#, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to override the following method of the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` in order to specify the size of my `UICollectionViewCell` :

```
    [MonoTouch.Foundation.Export("collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:")]
public virtual SizeF GetSizeForItem (UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, NSIndexPath indexPath)
```

To do so, I do the following:

```
type CollectionViewFlowDelegate (handle:IntPtr) as this = 
inherit UICollectionViewFlowLayout (handle)

override this.GetSizeForItem(collectionView : UICollectionView, layout : UICollectionViewLayout, indexPath : NSIndexPath) =
    CGSize(100.0, 300.0)
```

however, this throws an error saying there is no such method. I have opened the `F#` implementation of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, however I could not find this method there:

```
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using ObjCRuntime;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace UIKit
{
    [Register ("UICollectionViewFlowLayout", true), Introduced (PlatformName.iOS, 6, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null)]
    public class UICollectionViewFlowLayout : UICollectionViewLayout
    {
        //
        // Static Properties
        //
        [Field ("UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize", "UIKit"), Introduced (PlatformName.iOS, 10, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null), Introduced (PlatformName.TvOS, 10, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null)]
        public static CGSize AutomaticSize {
            [Introduced (PlatformName.iOS, 10, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null), Introduced (PlatformName.TvOS, 10, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null)]
            get;
        }

        //
        // Properties
        //
        public override IntPtr ClassHandle {
            get;
        }

        [Introduced (PlatformName.iOS, 8, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null), CompilerGenerated]
        public virtual CGSize EstimatedItemSize {
            [Export ("estimatedItemSize"), Introduced (PlatformName.iOS, 8, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null)]
            get;
            [Export ("setEstimatedItemSize:"), Introduced (PlatformName.iOS, 8, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null)]
            set;
        }

        [CompilerGenerated]
        public virtual CGSize FooterReferenceSize {
            [Export ("footerReferenceSize")]
            get;
            [Export ("setFooterReferenceSize:")]
            set;
        }

        [CompilerGenerated]
        public virtual CGSize HeaderReferenceSize {
            [Export ("headerReferenceSize")]
            get;
            [Export ("setHeaderReferenceSize:")]
            set;
        }

        [CompilerGenerated]
        public virtual CGSize ItemSize {
            [Export ("itemSize")]
            get;
            [Export ("setItemSize:")]
            set;
        }

        [CompilerGenerated]
        public virtual nfloat MinimumInteritemSpacing {
            [Export ("minimumInteritemSpacing")]
            get;
            [Export ("setMinimumInteritemSpacing:")]
            set;
        }

        [CompilerGenerated]
        public virtual nfloat MinimumLineSpacing {
            [Export ("minimumLineSpacing")]
            get;
            [Export ("setMinimumLineSpacing:")]
            set;
        }

        [CompilerGenerated]
        public virtual UICollectionViewScrollDirection ScrollDirection {
            [Export ("scrollDirection")]
            get;
            [Export ("setScrollDirection:")]
            set;
        }

        [Introduced (PlatformName.iOS, 9, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null), CompilerGenerated]
        public virtual bool SectionFootersPinToVisibleBounds {
            [Export ("sectionFootersPinToVisibleBounds"), Introduced (PlatformName.iOS, 9, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null)]
            get;
            [Export ("setSectionFootersPinToVisibleBounds:"), Introduced (PlatformName.iOS, 9, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null)]
            set;
        }

        [Introduced (PlatformName.iOS, 9, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null), CompilerGenerated]
        public virtual bool SectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds {
            [Export ("sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds"), Introduced (PlatformName.iOS, 9, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null)]
            get;
            [Export ("setSectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds:"), Introduced (PlatformName.iOS, 9, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null)]
            set;
        }

        [CompilerGenerated]
        public virtual UIEdgeInsets SectionInset {
            [Export ("sectionInset")]
            get;
            [Export ("setSectionInset:")]
            set;
        }

        [Introduced (PlatformName.iOS, 11, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null), Introduced (PlatformName.TvOS, 11, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null), Unavailable (PlatformName.WatchOS, PlatformArchitecture.All, null), CompilerGenerated]
        public virtual UICollectionViewFlowLayoutSectionInsetReference SectionInsetReference {
            [Export ("sectionInsetReference", ArgumentSemantic.Assign), Introduced (PlatformName.iOS, 11, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null), Introduced (PlatformName.TvOS, 11, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null), Unavailable (PlatformName.WatchOS, PlatformArchitecture.All, null)]
            get;
            [Export ("setSectionInsetReference:", ArgumentSemantic.Assign), Introduced (PlatformName.iOS, 11, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null), Introduced (PlatformName.TvOS, 11, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null), Unavailable (PlatformName.WatchOS, PlatformArchitecture.All, null)]
            set;
        }

        //
        // Constructors
        //
        [Export ("init"), EditorBrowsable (EditorBrowsableState.Advanced), CompilerGenerated]
        public UICollectionViewFlowLayout ();

        [Export ("initWithCoder:"), DesignatedInitializer, EditorBrowsable (EditorBrowsableState.Advanced), CompilerGenerated]
        public UICollectionViewFlowLayout (NSCoder coder);

        [EditorBrowsable (EditorBrowsableState.Advanced), CompilerGenerated]
        protected UICollectionViewFlowLayout (NSObjectFlag t);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[GetSizeForItem](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.GetSizeForItem/) is defined in `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

You have to create subclass derive from `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`,and assign it to `CollectionView.Delegate`.